# Merge different granularity data

Tags: database, data-modeling, data-warehouse

I have 2 tables with different granularity. First table has half an hour level granularity data as shown below -it shows that any system was in particular state during an half hour interval like state1, state2 and so on...

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>SysName</th>
    <th>StartTime</th>
    <th>EndTime</th>
    <th>State1</th>
    <th>State2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sys1</td>
    <td>12:00</td>
    <td>12:30</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sys2</td>
    <td>12:30</td>
    <td>01:00</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>18</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sys3</td>
    <td>01:00</td>
    <td>01:30</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>14</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**NOTE: - Here, I can easily apply custom filter of working hours/shifts like from morning 9.00 to evening 6.00 Or any other custom filter.**

And the other table has only the state changed data as shown below -

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>SysName</th>
    <th>StartTime</th>
    <th>EndTime</th>
    <th>Duration(mins)</th>
    <th>StateName</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sys1</td>
    <td>12:00</td>
    <td>12:45</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>State1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sys2</td>
    <td>12:45</td>
    <td>01:20</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>State2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sys3</td>
    <td>01:20</td>
    <td>04:00</td>
    <td>160</td>
    <td>State1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to merge this data into a single table in either of the granularity (which is the best suitable) and I should be able to apply the custom filters as well.

I am unable to take design decision here. Consider above 2 tables as Fact tables and suggest an approach so that I can merge it seamlessly and flow it to single fact table in Data Warehouse.

Comment: If possible, always go with the finest granularity. What are you trying to achieve? Do rules exist in how you have to present the data?

Comment: Yeah I can store data at the finest granularity. But this would result in million of records. E.g. 4000 systems * 730 (2 years data) * 48 (half an hour interval data) ~= 140160000 records.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Seems not too big to me. What about my other questions?

Comment: I want to show each system's performance by using different calculations based on various state's data. TOP 5 most/least used systems based on state info.Additionally, I want to apply custom calendars which I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Source data**

As you mentioned, your data looks like this:

Table 1:

```
SysName StartTime   EndTime State1  State2
Sys1    12:00       12:30   10      20
Sys2    12:30       01:00   12      18
Sys3    01:00       01:30   16      14
```

Table 2:

```
SysName StartTime   EndTime Duration(mins)  StateName
Sys1    12:00       12:45   45              State1
Sys2    12:45       01:20   35              State2
Sys3    01:20       04:00   160             State1
```

**Combination**

As I said before, I would always go with the lowest granularity possible. I have to assume a bit here since I don't know the source data exactly and the rule what data will count and which not - that is the reason why I added some *(?)*. So in my opinion the result of the rule to combine those two looks like this:

```
SysName StartTime  EndTime State1  State2 Duration  StateName
Sys1    12:00      12:30   10      20     (calcul.) State1
Sys1    12:30      12:45   0 (?)   0 (?)  (calcul.) State1
Sys2    12:30      12:45   12      18     (calcul.) NULL (?)
Sys2    12:45      01:00   12      18     (calcul.) State2
Sys2    01:00      01:20   0 (?)   0 (?)  (calcul.) State2
Sys3    01:00      01:20   16      14     (calcul.) NULL (?)
Sys3    01:20      01:30   16      14     (calcul.) State1
Sys3    01:30      04:00   0 (?)   0 (?)  (calcul.) State1
```

I didn't add the *Duration* since this field can be calculated easily on the fly. Anyways, if your rule is different than the one I assumed (basically: *if no state is found set 0 / NULL*), change it accordingly.

This should be a good foundation for your requirements and the analysis you want to do.